# Create a rewrite rule in htaccess for root of domain

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a RewriteRule in htaccess for the domain root without effecting all the links and images. For example I want to rewrite the domain only if a file or directory is not supplied, if there is a file or directory specified after the domain name I want the rule to be ignored.

Basically I'm just trying to rewrite `www.domain.com` to be `index.php?sectionID=1&page=1`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?sectionID=1&page=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?sectionID=1&page=1
```